# Unable to remove airflow table from airflow database on GCP (composer)

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, airflow, psql, google-cloud-composer

I have recently upgraded composer/airflow from 1.17/2.0 to 1.18/2.2 on GCP. Upon upgrade I see the following warnings on airflow UI:

*Airflow found incompatible data in the dag_run table in the metadatabase, and has moved them to **_airflow_moved__2_2__dag_run** during the database migration to upgrade. Please inspect the moved data to decide whether you need to keep them, and manually drop the **_airflow_moved__2_2__dag_run** table to dismiss this warning. Read more about it in [Upgrading](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.5/installation/upgrading.htmlv).*

and

*Airflow found incompatible data in the task_instance table in the metadatabase, and has moved them to **_airflow_moved__2_2__task_instance** during the database migration to upgrade. Please inspect the moved data to decide whether you need to keep them, and manually drop the **_airflow_moved__2_2__task_instance** table to dismiss this warning. Read more about it in [Upgrading](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.5/installation/upgrading.html).*

[image]

to remove the tables as instructed in the error message, i followed GCP documentation on [how to access the airflow database](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/access-airflow-database). once connected i see the tables listed however the following attempt to remove the tables doesn't work. no error message produced.

```
DROP TABLE public._airflow_moved__2_2__dag_run
DROP TABLE public._airflow_moved__2_2__task_instance
```

Comment: Do you have permission to delete the table in Cloud SQL?

Comment: @kiran-mathew it doesn't give me any permission error messages, how should i check for that?

Comment: You can check your service account permission on the IAM & Admin page of Google Cloud Console.  (Navigation menu → IAM & Admin → IAM ). You can  go through this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/iam-roles#roles) to check the roles and permissions needed to delete the tables.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for this, you can use the sqlalchemy library to inspect airflow metadata and then drop it.

- Create DAG
- Add the following function

---

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import text


def metadata_inspect():
    your_table_name = '_airflow_moved__2_2__task_instance'
    db_engine = create_engine(os.environ['AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN'])
    connection = db_engine.connect()
    query = text(f"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {your_table_name}")
    result = connection.execute(query)
    logging.info(result)
    connection.close()
    db_engine.dispose()
```

- Add PythonOperator Task that called this function

---

```
metadata_inspect = PythonOperator(task_id="metadata_inspect", python_callable=metadata_inspect)
```

*Note*
this param **AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN** may be different depending on your airflow version, for more info https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html